# VML href button gives me inverted colours

Tags: email, outlook, vml

I'm trying to make a button in VML for an email, but when I get it clicked, the colour changes to the invert of the colour I set as the background image. How can I set it to a colour that I set (as an onclick function or similar)or just remove the colour change?

```
<div><!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" stroke="false" fill="t" fillcolor="#652D89">
<v:fill type="solid" color="#652d89" /></v:fill>
<w:anchorlock/>
<center style="color:#0000ff;font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">This is a button!</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->


<a href="#" style="background-color:#652d89;border:1px solid #1e3650;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">This is a button!</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this: `<v:fill type="solid" color="#652d89" /></v:fill>`. I don't think that is needed for solid color buttons. It might be the cause...

Take a good look at the example on [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't do anything =/ Also, that is the page where I got the snippet from =P

Comment: I assumed that was where you got it, but noticed there was an extra bit of code in yours. I thought maybe you originally went with an image background button then removed it and left that piece in there. It was worth a try...